# How configure Azure function project in Intellij/Pycharm run/debug configurations on mac

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-configuration

How to configure Azure function project in Intellij/Pycharm run/debug configurations on Mac because I've tried to set it by my own but it doesnt work.

I would like to replace shell command: ***func start*** with ***run config***

The image below from Pycharm

[image: pycharm-azure config]

---

UPDATE

I've added path to Azure-CLI and imported my app-settings

[image]

I'm trying to configure the run configs but it asks to select the module but there is no any module in dropdown (see pic)

[image: intellij-azure config]

---

UPDATE-UPDATE:
[Here is what azure-tools-for-intellij team me answered:](https://github.com/JetBrains/azure-tools-for-intellij/issues/441#issuecomment-773848752)

[image]
They dont support pure python functions run yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to debug in ***Intellij Idea/PyCharm***.

1. add these lines at the top of your file/module:

```
import pydevd_pycharm
pydevd_pycharm.settrace('127.0.0.1', port=9091, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
```

[image]

2. set Python Debug Server with host and port in Run/Debug Configs
   [image: Screenshot at Feb 22 20-29-45]
3. run your azure functions as used to (`func host start`) and press debugging button.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't use row shell scrip with IntelliJ/PyCharm instead of this you should use [Azure Toolkit for IntelliJ](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8053-azure-toolkit-for-intellij) and run/debug your functions like in [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-intellij#debug-the-function-app-locally).

Also when you install Azure Toolkit for IntelliJ you will have the opportunity to create run/debug configuration with predefined Azure Function ready template.

Just example:

[image]

Comment: thanks, probably at that moment they havent been downloaded yet in Intellij. But in PyCharm there is no such Azure templates

Comment: @AlexNikonov are you still having problems with this, or did everything work out?

Comment: I've searched the toolkit manual for Python in ***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/*** but there is toolkit examples of *Java*. Could you see updated part of my question because I still have no idea what to set there as Module and I'm not sure if other fields are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it in PyCharm is to define a shell script configuration (Edit Configurations > Shell Script) and set:

- Execute: Script set
- Script text: func start
- Working directory: should be to project directory where host.json etc. is located
- Environment variables: leave empty
- Execute in the terminal: checked

Run this configuration, which will start the test server in terminal. Then go to Run > Attach to Process... and select the process (usually it's the one without any path after the number).